# Photoshop: change opacity of certain words in a text layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, transparency

It's a rather simple ordeal to change the color for certain words in a text field, but I'm also trying to change the opacity of certain words.

I want the whole text field to be at about 10% opacity, but certain words that I choose to be a different color and at 80% opacity. I don't know of any transparency controls on the character pallet.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a layer mask to text layers....

Add the mask set to reveal all (white)

Make a selection around the text you want to adjust opacity on.... then fill the selection with the percentage of black to indicate opacity.

80% black fill means the text will be seen at 20% opacity.

[image]

There is **no direct method** of altering opacity for individual characters within a text layer via the Character or Paragraph options.